# Override nVidia's 3D settings override

Tags: c++, nvidia

My application depends on `Antialising - Mode` being set to the default `Application-controlled`. It seems, since nVidia made it (way to) easy to override what an application would attempt to use, a disturbing percentage of users (roughly 1-2%) use non-default settings and then either (1) request support tickets, or (2) allege the application is poorly coded, when things go wrong.

Is there a way to detect or override whether the user is using nVidia's control panel to override settings? This is causing a customer support nightmare for me...

Answer (score 0):

In general: Having user-settings in the driver and letting the apps overide those settings any time would render the user-settings pretty pointless, wouldn't it? *Any* app would instantly decide what is best on behalf of the user.

That said: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi

Looking at `NvApiDriverSettings.h` I can spot a lot of AA related things:

```
AA_BEHAVIOR_FLAGS_ID                          = 0x10ECDB82,
AA_MODE_METHOD_ID                             = 0x10D773D2,
```

From what I have read in the docs you might generate an app-profile on the fly. You might have a problem with overriding things the user has set in the profile, but I don't know if that is the case.

I personally would not override any settings done by the user but instead display a warning that the user is running the app with unsupported settings (and thus invalidating his eventual "support tickets"). And, obviously, you have to do that with ATI and at least INTEL gpu-drivers as well.